# Error on bash in loop

Tags: bash

Trying to prepend all files in a directory with

```
line1
line2
line3
```

with this command:

```
$ for i in $(ls) ; perl -pi -e 'print "line1 \nline2\nline3\n" if $. == 1' $i ; done
```

but I have this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `perl'
```

perl command works for single file. Any explanation for the error?

Comment: [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) automatically points out your missing `do`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `do`...

```
for i in $(ls); 
do
    perl -pi -e 'print "line1 \nline2\nline3\n" if $. == 1' $i ; 
done
```